# Default display of annotations in Plotly/Python using a button

Tags: plotly-python

I managed the possibility to switch on and off the annotations in a plotly chart. After the executing the code i would like to see the chart without annotations and if required, the annotations could be activated (Label: OFF).

The following code displays per default the annotations and i am not able to set it up, that the first display of chart will be show without annotations.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# assign data of lists.  
data = {'x': ["2022-05-06", "2022-05-08", "2022-05-09", "2022-05-12", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-22", "2022-05-24", "2022-05-26"], 
        'y': [0, 1, 8, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5], 
        'text':["","","Annotation1","","Annotation2","","","","Annotation3"]}
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# assign data of lists.  
data1 = {'x': ["2022-05-07", "2022-05-14", "2022-05-23"], 
        'text':["Annotation1", "Annotation2", "Annotation3"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', title='Annotations ONN / OFF')

arrow_list=[]
counter=0
for i in df1['text'].tolist():
  if i != "":
    arrow=dict(x=df1['x'].values[counter],y=9,xref="x",yref="y",text=i,arrowhead = 2,ax=0,
               arrowwidth=1.5,
               bordercolor="#c7c7c7",
               borderwidth=2,
               borderpad=4,
               bgcolor="#ff7f0e",
               opacity=0.8,
            font=dict(
            family="Courier New, monospace",
            size=16,
            color="#ffffff"
            ),
               arrowcolor='rgb(255,51,0)',)
    arrow_list.append(arrow)
    counter+=1
  else:
    counter+=1
    

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
#            direction="right",
            active=0,
            showactive=True,
            buttons=list([
                
                dict(label="Label:Off",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                           {"annotations": []}]),

                dict(label="Label:On",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, True]},
                           {"annotations": arrow_list}]),

            ]),
        )
    ])




fig.update_layout(annotations=arrow_list)
fig.show()
```

I have tried to modify args and active, but without any success.

The first display of the charts (annotations should be off):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Load dataset
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Date': ["2022-05-06", "2022-05-08", "2022-05-09", "2022-05-12", "2022-05-15", "2022-05-16", "2022-05-22", "2022-05-24", "2022-05-26"], 
    'High': [0, 1, 8, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5], 
    'text':["","","Annotation1","","Annotation2","","","","Annotation3"]}

# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add Traces

fig.add_trace(
   go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date),
           y=list(df.High),
           name="High",
           line=dict(color="#33CFA5")))

arrow_list=[]
counter=0
for i in df1['text'].tolist():
  if i != "":
    arrow=dict(x=df1['x'].values[counter],y=9,xref="x",yref="y",text=i,arrowhead = 2,ax=0,
           arrowwidth=1.5,
           bordercolor="#c7c7c7",
           borderwidth=2,
           borderpad=4,
           bgcolor="#ff7f0e",
           opacity=0.8,
        font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=16,
        color="#ffffff"
        ),
           arrowcolor='rgb(255,51,0)',)
    arrow_list.append(arrow)
    counter+=1
  else:
    counter+=1


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Label: Off",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, False]},
                          {"title": "Labels Off",
                        "annotations": []}]),
                dict(label="Label: On",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "Labels On",
                        "annotations": arrow_list}]),

            ]),
        )
    ])


fig.show()
```